# Angular HTTP Interceptor not sending JWT

Tags: angular, http-headers

This is my auth service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ResolveStart, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { LoginPayload, newUser } from './auth';
import { config } from '../../config';
import { SnackbarService } from '../snackbar/snackbar.service';
import { HandleError, HttpErrorHandler } from '../http-error-handler.service'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  APIURL = `${config.apiUrl}/auth/`;
  private handleError: HandleError;
  currentUser = {};
  headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler,
    private snackBarService: SnackbarService,
    public router: Router
  ) {
    this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('AuthService')
  }

  signUp(user: newUser): Observable<any> {
    let api = `${this.APIURL}/signup`;
    return this.http.post(api, user).pipe(catchError(this.handleError('signUp', user)));
  }

  signIn(user: LoginPayload) {
    return this.http
      .post<any>(`${this.APIURL}signin`, user)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.accessToken);
        this.getUserProfile(res.username).subscribe((res) => {
          this.currentUser = res;
          this.router.navigate(['user/' + res.username]);
        });
      });
  }

  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token')
  }

  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    return authToken !== null ? true : false;
  }

  getUserProfile(username: any): Observable<any> {
    let api = `${this.APIURL}user/${username}`;
    return this.http.get(api, {headers: this.headers}).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        return res || {};
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError('getUserProfile', username))
    )
  }

  doLogOut() {
    let removeToken = localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    if (removeToken == null) {
      this.router.navigate(['login'])
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my HTTP Interceptor:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AuthService } from "./auth/auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const authToken = this.authService.getToken();
        const authReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken
            }
        });
        return next.handle(authReq);
    }
}
```

I'm able to retrieve the JWT from my API, and when I test my `getUserProfile` function using Postman I do get a response back, please see below:

[image: Postman Screenshot of get successful GET request]

The error I get is that the token is not being provided, however when I send it trough Postman, I can clearly see that is working, so there is nothing wrong with my backend API.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, in my API, I was requesting 'x-acccess-token' instead of Authorization, so I had to change that in the HTTP Interceptor and remove the 'Bearer' + part.